# Filling Multidimensional Array in PHP from DOMDocument

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am parsing a DOMDocument on documents that will have a predictable structure of `h3` and `li` tags that I am interested.  Currently I am using this function.

```
function showDOMNode(DOMNode $domNode) {
    foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node)
    {
            $myName = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $node->nodeName);
            $myValue = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $node->nodeValue);
            if ($myName=="h3" or $myName=="li" ){
                $myText = $myName.":".$myValue;
                print $myText;
                echo"\n";
            }
        if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            showDOMNode($node);
        }
    }   
}
```

Which gives the nice output of

```
h3:Category1 
li: Apple
li: Banana 
h3:Category2 
li: Ant 
h3:Category3
li: Alaska 
h3:Category4
li: Albania 
li: Bahamas
```

But would like to somehow put this into a multidimensional array.  `$myArray[][]` where the first dimension is the `h3` value and the `li` values are placed into the appropriate `h3` array.

```
function showDOMNode(DOMNode $domNode, $arrayToFill) {
    foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node)
    {
            $myName = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $node->nodeName);
            $myValue = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $node->nodeValue);
            if ($myName=="h3" or $myName=="li" ){
                //somehow insert $myValue into $arrayToFill maybe???
            }
        if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            showDOMNode($node,$arrayToFill);
        }
    }  
    return $arrayToFill;  
}
```

Or if there is a much easier way to do all of this I am open to anything.  The data structure will always have `li` tags separated by `h3` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the `somehow insert $myValue` code:

```
if ($myName == "h3") {
    if (!isset($arrayToFill[$myValue])) {
        $arrayToFill[$myValue] = array();
    }
    $curElement = $myValue;
} elseif ($myName == "li") {
    $arrayToFill[$curElement][] = $myValue;
}
```

This should return an array like:

```
[ "Category1" => [ "Apple", "Banana" ],
  "Category2" => [ "Ant" ],
  "Category3" => [ "Alaska" ],
  "Category4" => [ "Albania", "Bahamas" ]
]
```

Also, when you perform the recursive call, you're not picking up the returned array:

```
$arrayToFill = showDOMNode($node, $arrayToFill);
```

You could also solve this by taking the `$arrayToFill` argument by reference:

```
function showDOMNode(DOMNode $domNode, &$arrayToFill) {
```

Then modifications to the array in the function would be seen in the caller.

We also need to pass `$curElement` into the recursive call. I pass this as a reference as well, so that updates to it will be reflected in the caller.

```
function showDOMNode(DOMNode $domNode, &$arrayToFill, &$curElement = null) {
    foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node)
    {
            $myName = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $node->nodeName);
            $myValue = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $node->nodeValue);
            if ($myName == "h3") {
                if (!isset($arrayToFill[$myValue])) {
                    $arrayToFill[$myValue] = array();
                }
                $curElement = $myValue;
            } elseif ($myName == "li") {
                $arrayToFill[$curElement][] = $myValue;
            }
        if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            showDOMNode($node, $arrayToFill, $curElement);
        }
    }  
    return $arrayToFill;  
}
```

Comment: This perfectly creates the first levels, but instead of, say, `["Apple","Banana"]` it just returns an empty array, `=> Array()` for the 2nd level items.

Comment: I put in an echo statement, so it's definitely iterating through those `li` items, but just not storing them anywhere...

Comment: Okay, I replaced `showDOMNode($node,$arrayToFill);` with `$arrayToFill = showDOMNode($node, $arrayToFill);` and it returned the same array of empty 1st level arrays, except the 2nd item in the array was an unnamed array with every single `li` item in the same array.  Taking the array argument by reference did the same thing.  Let me make sure I'm doing what you said.  Here's what I'm getting. `Array( [Category1] => Array(),
  []=>Array(Apple, Banana, Ant, Alaska, Albania, Bahamas),
  [Category2] => Array(),
  [Category3] => Array(),
  [Category4] => Array()
)`

Comment: Okay, debugging, I see that the elseif part is not getting the $curElement  value passed to it.  It thinks that $curElement is empty it appears.

Comment: Oh, right. It's a variable scope issue -- `$curElement` is in the parent call. We need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: OK. I'll try setting that up and for the initial function call just pass an empty string.

Comment: Whoop!  That worked.  I'm not very good at programming concepts.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: I see your update.  I will use $curElement as a reference and `=null`.